# how to write if and else statement inside single quote?

Tags: javascript

I have been tried to check an if statement inside single quote but I got an error which is :
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if` , my code :

```
<script>
   for($i=0;$i<len;$i++){
    text='<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 pull-right text-left-sm star_div" >'+
                                '<h5 class="star_h5" >'+

                                    if(1=1){
                                    }

                                ' </h5>'+
                                '</div>';
        }
</script>
```

my goal I want to check if and else statement inside single quote?

Comment: `if(1=1){` should be comparing like  `if(1==1){` please post your actual code...

Comment: but there is alot of codes I just post my idea, there is many calculation inside if statment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   for ($i = 0; $i < len; $i++) {
       text = '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 pull-right text-left-sm star_div" >' +
           '<h5 class="star_h5" >' +

           ((1 == 1) ? 'ONE' : 'NOT ONE')

       + ' </h5>' + '</div>';
   }
```

OR

```
  for (var $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
       text = '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 pull-right text-left-sm star_div" >' +
           '<h5 class="star_h5" >' +

           (function () {
             if (1 == 1) {
               return 'ONE';
             }

             return ''; 
           }())

       + ' </h5>' + '</div>';
   }
```